# Wordpress add code to specific page <head> tag

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm on wordpress. I'm trying to add an opengraph tag just to my homepage (my other pages use a plugin to add these tags).

I found this from another question but it doesn't work. I'm pasting this in my header.php file.

```
if (is_page('home')) { <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $img_src; ?>"/> }
```

Comment: Please try is_front_page();

Comment: That didn't work either.

Comment: Is it showing any error? Can you paste the correct code here. The code you pasted here seems to have a syntax error. It doesn't have PHP open close tags for embedding html

Comment: I also tried your edited code with the php tags and that gave me an error. The above code doesnt work but it doesnt give an error. Can you check your php syntax again?

Comment: Can you paste the error which you got after editing

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate and check for page using wordpress conditional tags, for more information check this link out https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

For Static Page selected from Administration > Settings > Reading. use is_front_page(). They can be used in template files.

Comment: I tried that with the syntax in my question and it didn't work. Is there another  issue in the code I have above?

Comment: i tried `if (is_front_page()) { <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $img_src; ?>"/> }`